# STM32F373 Input Capture

Tags: timer, stm32f3

I am having an issue trying to get Input capture to work on one of the stm32f373 pins (PB0, TIM3 CH2 ). The reason why i'm stuck with this pin is because m doing this on my own personalized board with stm32f373rbt6. The rest of the pins are either taken or dont have corresponding functionality attached to them. I'm certain that the pcb is fine and traces are fine (did a continuity check from the source to the pin). On stm32f373rbt6, PB0 could also be configured as an analog input for the built in sigma-delta ADC module. But since my project does not require any adc i havent even touched or configured it anywhere in my code. Below is the code and the corresponding IRQ Handler.

Please do let me know if you find any configuration errors.

```
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA,ENABLE);
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB,ENABLE);
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2,ENABLE);
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3,ENABLE);

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_5;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA,GPIO_PinSource5,GPIO_AF_1);
GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_0;
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB,GPIO_PinSource0,GPIO_AF_2);
GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&GPIO_InitStructure);

TIM_ICInitTypeDef TIM_ICInitStruct;
TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_Channel=TIM_Channel_1;
TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_ICPolarity=TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_ICPrescaler=TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_ICFilter=0x0;
TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_ICSelection=TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;

TIM_ICInit(TIM2,&TIM_ICInitStruct);
TIM2->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E;


TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_Channel=TIM_Channel_2;
TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_ICPolarity=TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_ICSelection=TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
TIM_ICInit(TIM3,&TIM_ICInitStruct);
TIM3->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC2E;

TIM_Cmd(TIM3,ENABLE);
TIM_Cmd(TIM2,ENABLE);

NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM2_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM3_IRQn;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

TIM_ITConfig(TIM2,TIM_IT_CC1,ENABLE);
TIM_ITConfig(TIM3,TIM_IT_CC2 ,ENABLE);


void TIM3_IRQHandler(void){
__disable_irq();
++capture;
GPIOE->ODR ^=GPIO_Pin_9;
if((TIM3->SR & TIM_SR_CC2IF))
{
    GPIOE->ODR ^=GPIO_Pin_9;
    TIM3->SR=(uint16_t)~TIM_SR_CC2IF;
}
EncoderFreqQuery(TIM3,&RightFreq);
__enable_irq();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the datasheet PB0 AF2 is **TIM3_CH3** and **not** TIM3_CH2. I would change to this:

```
TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_Channel=TIM_Channel_3;
TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_ICPolarity=TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
TIM_ICInitStruct.TIM_ICSelection=TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
TIM_ICInit(TIM3,&TIM_ICInitStruct);
```

Or just change to AF10 for PB0 (which happens to be PB0 TIM3_CH2):

```
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_0;
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB,GPIO_PinSource0,GPIO_AF_10);
GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&GPIO_InitStructure);
```